# Unable to find source for mystery Excel User Defined Functions appearing in the "Insert Function" dialog box

Tags: excel, excel-addins, excel-udf

My list of User Defined Functions contains 118 unknown and unidentifiable functions that I can't identify or delete. These UDF's appear to be associate with the Excel Solver, and are named using several different languages (French, Italian, English, German etc.). Even if I start with an fresh and therefore empty PERSONAL.XLSB file, these UDF's show up in the Insert Function... dialog box in Excel. None of these UDF's are supplemented with a Help file.

Where, other than PERSONAL.XLSB, might I go searching for these UDF's so I can delete them and remove them from the Insert Function... dialog box as they clutter up this dialog and make the management and use of actual UDF's I've created very difficult.

I have attached an image that contains the listing of UDF's I am referring to.

Thanks for any and all comments on what might be happening here... it has me stumped.

I have searched the internet without success. The same issue was noted through a question in the Microsoft Tech Community site, but no answers were provided.

[text](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/solver-causes-non-english-functions-to-appear/m-p/1154513)

I expect but can't confirm that this may be a glitch in the Solver Add-in within Excel.

Comment: Yes, these are from the Solver Add-in.

Comment: ^^^ not sure what you want us to do about it.  Once you install the add-in, they are there.  Short of removing and reinstalling Excel, they will be there.  I mean if Microsoft's own community does not have an answer, how would we?

Comment: You could edit the Solver.XLAM file to make these functions `Private`. The password can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345254/excel-solver-password-what-is-it-and-where-can-it-be-acquired-bought).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response BigBen, and most importantly the password. Most appreciated. Am working through the .xlam, found the culprits and am sure this can be resolved. Many thanks. TB